# In JavaScript is there a strict equivalent of || when used in assignment of variables?

Tags: javascript

I have been working on a piece of code that had a set of computations resulting in a new position of another object. Something like the following:

```
if (foo.length === 0) {
    position = 'something';
} else if ((position = bar.compute()) !== false) {
    // do nothing
} else if ((position = baz.compute()) !== false) {
    // do nothing
} else {
    position = 'some default';
}
```

now looking at this code it looks a bit off to me. A lot actually. I could do the compute() method on bar and baz again inside the body of the if statement but that means double compute time. the compute method itself tries to find a new position and returns false when it does not.

naturally I thought of this as a more elegant coding solution:

```
if (foo.length === 0) {
    position = 'something';
} else {
    position = bar.compute() || baz.compute() || 'some default';
}
```

However this won't work as the compute method can also return a value 0. This should be returned and assigned to the position but it does not. Why? the comparator is not strict.

Is there a way to use this last suggested style of assignment and get 0 to be returned as the position? is there an equivalent of '===' for '||'?

EDIT: note that this is a hypothetical case where x = a || b || c the cases can be a number 0 to N or false when the value is not found. problem is that false == 0 and this is used during assignment.

EDIT: added origin code block change by @T.J.Crowder

Comment: Why do you want a more strict version of `||` when the original code does not accept the value of `0` anyway? (in other words, the original code is also non-strict)

Comment: What value does `compute` return that you want to use `'some default'` instead? As slebetman says, your current code doesn't keep the `0` either. We can't answer the question until we know when `'some default'` should be used.

Comment: To put it another way, the new code perfectly emulates the behavior of the old code. If it doesn't do what you're expecting then what you really want is to change the behavior of the old code (the if..else..else)

Comment: ***sigh*** Another ask-and-run.

Comment: sorry, had to commute @T.J.Crowder.

Comment: it's a basic A, B, C where A should be assigned if it returns a value. if that's not the case it should be B. if that is not the case it should be C

this works: x = undefined || false || 1
x is now 1

y = undefined || 2 || 1
y = now 2

Comment: @slebetman the core returns a number that could be 0. or false when it cannot find a value. I would call that strict. But in a non-strict compare 0 == false and that makes the x = foo || bar be an issue

Comment: @yopefonic: Well, that's not what the first code block above does. Again, it will assign `'some default'` if both `compute`s return `0`.

Comment: @yopefonic: How can the code return 0? `else if (position = bar.compute())` cannot return 0 it would go to else. Then `else if (position = baz.compute())` cannot return 0 it would go to else which in turn returns `'some defalut'`. If the code returns 0 it's not in the logic you've posted.

Comment: @slebetman bar.compute() returns a number 0 to N or when it cannot find a value it returns false

Comment: @yopefonic: I understand that. But the `if...` basically becomes `if(0)` when `bar.compute()` returns 0 so `position` will never be assigned 0. What's the difference then between the original code and the new code?

Answer (score 1):

> the core returns a number that could be 0. or false when it cannot find a value

<s>Your first code block will assign `'some default'` if both `compute`s return `0`. If you want to only continue when `compute` returns `false`, your first code block would need to be:</s>

```
if (foo.length === 0) {
    position = 'something';
} else if ((position = bar.compute()) !== false) {
    // do nothing
} else if ((position = baz.compute()) !== false) {
    // do nothing
} else {
    position = 'some default';
}
```

*(You've since edited the question to copy the above into it.)*

or condensing that a bit:

```
if (foo.length === 0) {
    position = 'something';
} else if ((position = bar.compute()) !== false ||
           (position = baz.compute()) !== false) {
    // do nothing
} else {
    position = 'some default';
}
```

or something similar using `typeof` to see whether you got back a `"number"`.

> Is there a way to use this last suggested style of assignment and get 0 to be returned as the position? is there an equivalent of '===' for '||'?

No, there isn't. You can still use `||`, but it'll be more complicated to read and debug. For instance, this would probably work:

```
if (foo.length === 0) {
    position = 'something';
} else {
    (position = bar.compute()) !== false || (position = bar.compute()) !== false || (position = 'some default');
}
```

...but that's pretty hard to understand, arguably an "abusage" of the `||` rather than a usage of it. You could probably come up with a complicated use of the conditional operator (`? :`), but it would be similarly more awkward to read and debug.

Just proving to myself that the abusage works:

```js
var foo = ['one'];

test(false, false);
test(0, false);
test(false, 0);
test(1, false);
test(false, 1);

function test(c1value, c2value) {
  var position;
  
  if (foo.length === 0) {
    position = 'something';
  } else {
    (position = c1value) !== false || (position = c2value) !== false || (position = 'some default');
  }

  snippet.log("position for " + c1value + ", " + c2value + ": " + position);
}
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```